# MongoDb in a shared web hosting

Tags: php, mongodb, ionos

Can I use MongoDb in a share web hosting like IONOS?
I tried to connect my webapp to an Atlas Cluster:

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb+srv://.....');
```

but it show this error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found
```

I can't add en extension on my php.ini or somethings like this. Do i need to switch to a VPS?

Comment: That looks like a good question for your hosting provider